# couldn't resolve memory error in python numpy zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm getting a memory error on the following line -

```
Z = np.zeros((m, n_H, n_W, n_C))
```

the values are

```
m = 982, n_H = 400, n_W = 400, n_C = 3
```

Please help.
Here is the code I'm working on -

```
def conv_forw(A_prev, W, b, hparameters):      
    (m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev) = A_prev.shape
    (f, f, n_C_prev, n_C) = W.shape
    stride = hparameters['stride']
    pad = hparameters['pad']
    n_H = int((n_H_prev - f + 2 * pad) / stride) + 1
    n_W = int((n_W_prev - f + 2 * pad) / stride) + 1
    Z = np.zeros((m, n_H, n_W, n_C))
    A_prev_pad = zero_pad(A_prev, pad)

    for i in range(m):                                 
        a_prev_pad = A_prev_pad[i]                     
        for h in range(n_H):                           
            for w in range(n_W):                       
                for c in range(n_C):                   
                    vert_start = h * stride
                    vert_end = vert_start + f
                    horiz_start = w * stride
                    horiz_end = horiz_start + f
                    a_slice_prev = a_prev_pad[vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end, :]
                    Z[i, h, w, c] = conv_single_layer(a_slice_prev, W[...,c], b[...,c])

    assert(Z.shape == (m, n_H, n_W, n_C))
    cache = (A_prev, W, b, hparameters)    
    return Z, cache
```

Here's the error -

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-346685ab9b7c> in <module>()
----> 1 (Z1, cache1) = conv_forw(X, W, b, hparameters)

<ipython-input-4-64ab3cc0c83f> in conv_forw(A_prev, W, b, hparameters)
      6     n_H = int((n_H_prev - f + 2 * pad) / stride) + 1
      7     n_W = int((n_W_prev - f + 2 * pad) / stride) + 1
----> 8     Z = np.zeros((m, n_H, n_W, n_C))
      9     A_prev_pad = zero_pad(A_prev, pad)
     10 

MemoryError:
```

Comment: No erros in Python 3.7, numpy 1.15.4

Comment: Can you please paste the actual error you are seeing? Also, how much memory do you have?

Comment: It's giving me errors when I use the function in the following line `(Z1, cache1) = conv_forw(X, W, b, hparameters)`

Comment: Added the error in question

Comment: @RishabhKumar please paste it into the question for newlines formatting... It's not readable like this

Comment: @M.Volf added the error in question

Comment: @lxop I've 8GB RAM

Comment: You're missing the end of the error report

Comment: @lxop that's the whole error

Answer (score 1):

You're running out of memory, because you're creating an array of 982 arrays which each contain 400 arrays which each contain 400 arrays which each contain 3 zeroes. That's 471360000 fields.

Comment: Well, I neither have experience with numpy (I just found [numpy.zeroes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) docs) nor really understand what your code does.